# JPA createQuery or @NamedQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Is it better to use a single query using `@NamedQuery` to get results in a single row or use `createQuery`?

I have the following  in DAOImpl

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Project> c = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
Root<Project> prj = c.from(Project.class);
c.orderBy(cb.desc(prj.get("projectNo")));
c.select(prj);

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Project> prjCount = countQ.from(Project.class);
countQ.select(cb.count(prjCount ));

String projectNo = filters.get("projectNo");

List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    if (projectNo != null) {
        ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class,
            "projectNo");
    Predicate predicate = cb.like(prj.get(Project_.projectNo),
                    pexp);
            criteria.add(predicate);
        }
 if (criteria.size() == 1) {
    c.where(criteria.get(0));
        countQ.where(criteria.get(0));
    } else if (criteria.size() > 1) {
        c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        countQ.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        }

 TypedQuery<Project> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);
 TypedQuery<Long> countquery = entityManager.createQuery(countQ);
```

In `TypedQuery` I could use either `createQuery` or call `createNamedQuery` defined in Entity class.

Reason why I have used `createQuery` is because I would like to filter and get results based on filter condition. Whereas If I am using `createNamedQuery`, then I need to add a where condition in `@NamedQuery` and most importantly I need to check whether filter condition is null or not, if it is null then I use some kind of wild character like `%` to get all the results from database which can cause a delay.

So I have two doubts

- Is it better to use `createQuery` to use the filter or search
  effectively, there by execute multiple sql statements which are based
  on my mappings and joins?
- Is it better to use `@NamedQuery` and have a where condition and
  execute only one sql with joins?

Any insight or input or help are highly appreciable.

Comment: maybe [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596025/hibernate-named-queries-and-its-performance-advantage) will help.

Comment: @Angga Was wondering does it have any performance issue when `createQuery` is used as it executes multiple sql statements rather than a single sql in case of `@NamedQuery` because of `join fetch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `@NamedQuery` is just like `typedQuery`, typedQuery is the result of create query:

```
TypedQuery<USER> hql = entityManager.createQuery(query);
```

The only difference between `@NamedQuery` and `typedQuery` is named query is on the difference place than the code, and checked when the session factory is created.

Performance issue difference is just about building strings, so unless your join is in a hundred or thousands of table you really won't find any difference about those two.

Comment: Angga `@NamedQuery` and `createQuery`, not `typedQuery` :-) I do not have hundreds of table join, less than 10 or 15. So I do not think this will have any performance issue whether one single query executes in the case of `@NamedQuery` because I have `join fetch` defined to join tables. Although In order to use filter condition I am using `createQuery`.

Comment: sorry, maybe what i said and my code example have missmatch. what i said is `.createQuery()` have return type of TypedQuery and `.CreateNamedQuery()` also return a TypedQuery. so the two of them have exactly the same SQL generated value if the HQL is the same, the difference is just where they get the String.

Comment: The _results_ are the same but the question was which is _better_. a `@NamedQuery` may be pre-compiled when the application starts up in which case it would be more efficient.

Comment: yes, that is the only difference in performance, as i said in my answer, its **"checked when the session factory is created"**, so when @NamedQuery have an error, the application will fail fast, without too much unit testing. I thing my answer is clear enough, that two of them didn't have major difference, much less in performance. this is like the difference of a `public static String` variable vs normal `private String` variable.